# UIDocumentMenuViewController buttons not doing anything

Tags: ios, button, document, ios8, ios-app-extension

So I'm testing out Apple's new Document Provider extension. I'm trying to open up a UIDocumentMenuViewController up, and that part is working. But when I try to click on one of the items it presents, it just cancels the action sheet. This happens even when I click on the iCloud item, which is there by default. My code for presenting the controller is as follows:

```
let type_data = kUTTypeData.__conversion()
let documentMenuViewController = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes:   [type_data], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
navigationController.presentViewController(documentMenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Wasn't implementing the delegate methods...woops

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the delegate on the `UIDocumentMenuViewController`. Then implement the `-documentMenu:didPickDocumentPicker:` delegate method. Then you can go ahead and present the `documentPicker` that was selected.

```
func documentMenu(documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController!, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController!) {
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

There is a simple example of this [here in Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the NewBox Apple sample code and you'll see the step you are missing.  Can't provide the actual answer here as iOS 8 is still under NDA.